# Unexpected token 1fr in wordpress editor

Tags: css

I just want to ask a simple question.
When I try to style the HTML element in the style.css file. And after applying the style which looks like:

```
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

But the wordpress editor shows error: unexpected token '1fr'.
Can you just tell me why it is showing if the CSS property is right?
Thanks

Comment: It's normal, the Wordpress editor isn't configured to consider those properties .. so simply don't pay attention ... as you can see here : https://jsfiddle.net/jzbhpns3/ the CSS is valid